# How to add additional job params that are substituted to CoreBackgroundJobPerformer in Hangfire.io

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, hangfire

In the excellent hangfire.io library [jobs can be executed with special params that are substituted at job execution such as IJobCancellationToken](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html) which allows you to cancel a job. Similarly PerformContext can be added as a param at runtime. This functionality is implemented in the [CoreBackgroundJobPerformer](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Server/CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.cs)

How can I add my own customised substitutions so I can change the substitution behaviour to substitute my own params at job execution in addition to the built in param substitutions?

AFAIK I would need to implement a custom IBackgroundJobPerformer that would be created by a custom [BackgroundJobServer](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.Core/BackgroundJobServer.cs#L134). But is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is not an easy way to do this and would probably require some changes in hangfire or running a forked version. Further discussion of how this may be implemented is at https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1221